# Is there ongoing research on Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithms (other than Metropolis-Hastings) for use in ray tracing?

Tags: computer-vision, graphics

Metropolis Light Transport is an application of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Its variants differ only in the used "mutation strategy".

Is there ongoing research on other Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithms (with faster convergence rates) for use in ray tracing?

If so, I'm interested in any paper.

([Cross-posted](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/7965/is-there-ongoing-research-on-markov-chain-monte-carlo-algorithms-other-than-met) on Computer Graphics)

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Computer Graphics.